# Como salvo um áudio em uma pasta com o gtts usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou escrevendo um programa em JavaScript e preciso salvar um arquivo de áudio usando gtts ou qualquer outra biblioteca de som.
Meu código:

```
var texto = "Preciso ser um arquivo de áudio";
var filepath = "mp3/song.wav";

gtts.save(filepath, texto, function() {
console.log(`${filepath} MP3 SALVO`)
});
```

Comment: Vê só
Esse código vai rodar no cliente ou no servidor? Ou ... isso tá numa página html ou está num node.js ? Se estiver na página, o que você tem que fazer é fazer um download do arquivo de som que foi gerado. Javascript não pode gravar no disco do cliente. Só através de download.

Comment: Ele está sendo executado no node.js

Comment: E o conteúdo do arquivo de som, onde está ?